# Ubuntu 11.10 Adobe PDF 9 not associated correctly

Tags: 11.10, pdf, adobe

I have had problems associated Adobe PDF reader in Ubuntu for a long time.  Any time I have needed to open a PDF for example in firefox or a downloaded PDF i have to manually open the file after opening Adobe PDF reader.  I recently un-installed Adobe PDF reader today trying to fix this issue planning on re-installing it later and noticed that there is an app in the system menu called adobe pdf reader 9 still lingering when i did a search for adobe.  when I tried to launch the app after un-installing it it gave me an error message failed to launch child process and is looking in my download directory.

Does anyone know how to remove this bogus link from my system menu, i think it may be causing the file association problems.

Thank you,

Mixphonics

Comment: I work a lot with PDF files on daily basis, I find the opensource alternatives to adobe pdf viewer much more intuitive and faster. They have all the features you would need. My favourites are  Document Viewer that is installed by default in Ubuntu and Okular that has some nice extra features. If you need to edit/modify pdf files there are several great tools available in the repository as well.

Answer (score 1):

The brocken link in your system menu is not causing the problem with file association. You can easily change the default associated file by right clicking on any PDF and selecting **Properties** from the menu. Choose the **Open With** tab and you will see the default program as well. You can change the default by selecting another program from the recommended application list and select **Set as default**.

[image]

Here is I select Set as default, Okular will be set for viewing all PDF files from now on until I change the default again.

If you like to open your PDF file with another application that is not set as default, you can always right click on a file and choose the desired application from the Open With sub-menu.